# Hide a config value for storm UI

Tags: java, apache-storm

Storm UI shows all the configuration value including the blowfish encryption key. Is there any way to hide some of the config value from public?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such option provided out of the box.

If you just need to hide a some value from UI there is a simple hack. Just edit:

**[storm_home]/public/index.html**

In the bottom of the code there is a call to configuration parameters. You just need a small change here to hide parameters from UI. For example, I want to hide this parameter - **dev.zookeeper.path**.

**index.html** (UI/source)

[image]

```
$.getJSON("/api/v1/cluster/configuration",function(response,status,jqXHR) {
  var formattedResponse = formatConfigData(response);
  $.get("/templates/index-page-template.html", function(template) {
    config.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter("#configuration-template").html(),formattedResponse));
    $('#nimbus-configuration-table td').jsonFormatter()
    //key, value
    dtAutoPage("#nimbus-configuration-table", {});
    $('#nimbus-configuration [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
});
```

Now I added code to hide this parameter and reloaded the page. There is no **dev.zookeeper.path** property displayed.

**index.html** (UI/source)
[image]

```
$.getJSON("/api/v1/cluster/configuration",function(response,status,jqXHR) {
  delete response["dev.zookeeper.path"];
  var formattedResponse = formatConfigData(response);
  $.get("/templates/index-page-template.html", function(template) {
    config.append(Mustache.render($(template).filter("#configuration-template").html(),formattedResponse));
    $('#nimbus-configuration-table td').jsonFormatter()
    //key, value
    dtAutoPage("#nimbus-configuration-table", {});
    $('#nimbus-configuration [data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
});
```

**Note:** this way is not secure and just hide property on UI, but the property still available through the direct HTTP call to:
http://[host_name]:[port]/api/v1/cluster/configuration

If you need really secure solution, you have to read **Running Apache Storm Securely - UI/Logviewer** section.
http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/SECURITY.html